# Error when setting `listen_address= '*'` in postgresql.conf file trying to run postgresql db

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, airflow

My main purpose of trying to run postgresql is for running airflow locally on my machine. I went to `etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf` and changed the following:

```
#listen_addresses = 'localhost'         # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
listen_addresses = ‘*’                  # for Airflow connection
# — Connection Settings -
#listen_addresses = ‘localhost’ # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
```

After changing this running the command `sudo -u postgres psql` gives me the error:

```
Error: invalid line 63 in /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf: listen_addresses = ‘*’                  # for Airflow connection
```

Any advice would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: `'*'` not `‘*’`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a typing error it should have been '*' not `*`. Answer given by horse_with_no_name